# How to reload script after ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using infinite scroll and social share buttons after loading more results aren't appearing.  I need to reload the script for the buttons to appear?  I'm using the add to any plugin and they script is `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js"> </script>`  How do i reload this script so that the buttons appear?  I added this code but only the facebook and twitter buttons appeared after ajax loaded new results not the google plus and pinterest...

```
jQuery('body').trigger( 'post-load');
```

How do i solve this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the .ajaxComplete(function().

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxComplete handler." );
});
```

See more [here.](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/)

Or you can use the jQuery.GetScript()

```
$.getScript( "ajax/test.js" )
  .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
    console.log( textStatus );
  })
  .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
    $( "div.log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
});
```

See more [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/).

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
 a2a.dom.ready(function(){a2a.init_all();a()});
});
```

or

```
 $( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    if(document.body){a2a.init();a()} a2a.dom.ready(function(){a2a.init_all();a()});
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for this but how do i trigger this code `http://static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js` in jquery?

Comment: Thanks for this, i tried but the images are still missing?  The only thing loading are the anchor tags?

Comment: Only thing that gets the facebook and twitter images to show is `jQuery('body').trigger( 'post-load');`  any idea why the google plus and pinterest buttons aren't showing?